# laravel5.1 retrieve nested relation using eloquent hasOne() (one to one relation)

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, relationship, one-to-one

My table design is:

```
users: | id  |username | ... |

tickets: | id | supp_id | ... |

ticket_replies: | id | ticket_id | user_id |
```

My controllers look like:

user:

```
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ticket');
}
```

ticket:

```
public function ticket_replie()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ticket_replie');
}

public function supporter()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id','supp_id');
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
$tickets =  Auth::user()->tickets()->orderBy('status', 'desc')->paginate(2);

return view('protected.ticketsList', [ 
    'tickets' => $tickets,
]);
```

In my view I use:

```
 supporter: {{ $ticket['supporter']->username }}
```

Any idea where I do wrong? I get all the time this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

In my point of view the relation between the tables itself is done correctly.
When I use for example `{{ dd($ticket) }}` in my view I get an object with all the items I need:

[image]

Comment: Does `$ticket->supporter()->first()->username` work? Or `$ticket->supporter()->username` (not sure if you need the `->first()` in this situation)

Comment: Works, but why did I need to use "first()"? I can't understand this, there is just ONE supporter for each ticket! What's the sense to use "first()", it just don't feel like the correct way?!

Comment: I'll write a quick answer for you. The usage is a little bizarre, but I can show you an easy way to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, trying to access the function `public function supporter()` on your `Ticket` model cannot be done using array syntax. Change:

```
{{ $ticket['supporter']->username }}
```

to:

```
{{ $ticket->supporter()->first()->username }}
```

If you don't want to use the `->first()` you can do one of two things. Modify your existing query to include the `->with("supporter")` syntax:

```
$tickets = Auth::user()
           ->tickets()
           ->with("supporter")
           ->orderBy('status', 'desc')
           ->paginate(2);
```

And access the supporter from the view like so:

```
{{ $ticket->supporter->username }}
// Notice how supporter is no longer a `method` ->supporter() but a `property` ->supporter
```

Or you can modify your relationship to include the closer `->first()`:

```
public function supporter(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id','supp_id')->first();
}
```

And then access it like so:

```
{{ $ticket->supporter()->username }}
// Notice you no longer need `->first()`
```

So, as you can see, there are multiple ways to access a `Ticket`'s `Supporter`. Please note that you can't really combine these options; modifying the function to include `->first()` and then trying to use `->with()` will return an error, so pick one or the other.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But I use the "official" way, so there is no way to "prevent" "first()? It's just a bit absurd for me to think about. Use "first()" to get the first element which just could be one! I use correct way and relation ship, right?

Comment: I'm not really sure what is considered the *official* way. It really depends on where you're using your `supporter()` function. On the back end, use `->with()` on the query. If you're calling it from a view, have the closure `->first()` in the function. But again, I don't know the official answer; this is all from my experience.

Comment: Haha yeah, the key is to be consistent and learn what works best for you. Performance wise, I doubt there would be any noticeable difference. To be honest, my way is significantly more convoluted than this answer. I modify each function to include a `$closure = false` variable, and return different things depending on whether or not you override this variable. This way I can use both methods `Ticket::with("supporter")->get(); [...] $ticket->supporter->username` and `->supporter(true)->username` interchangeably.